# How to include both dynamic select menu and nested attributes together in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Consider i have three tables users, countries, states. I have a page to add a new user and when i add a new user i have to list the countries in the select box and on selecting the country the multiple select box should be loaded with the states of the country and i should be able to select the desired states.

Similarly i can click on the add button to add another select box and select another country and select states that belongs to that country and so on. And i know this needs nested attributes and dynamic select menu functionality but do not know how i can use these together.

The following are the ones that i tried

**Models:**

```
class Country < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :states
  attr_accessible :name
end
```

and

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
     serialize :state_id
    has_many :user_countries
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_countries, :allow_destroy => true
    has_many :state
    attr_accessible :username, :user_countries_attributes
end
```

and

```
class State < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :country
    attr_accessible :name, :country_id
end
```

and

```
class UserCountry < ActiveRecord::Base
    serialize :state_id
    belongs_to :users
    attr_accessible :country_id, :user_id, :state_id
end
```

Also the following image shows what i am trying to accomplish clearly

[image]

**UPDATE**

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <% if @user.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this user from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :username %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :username %>
  </div>
      <%= f.fields_for :user_countries do |country| %>
        <%= render "user_country_fields", :f => country %>
      <% end %>
    <div class="add_variant"><%= link_to_add_fields "Add Country", f, :user_countries %></div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**Update1:**

```
<div class="entry_field">
    <label>Country :</label>
    <div id="field_country">

      <%= f.collection_select :country_id, Country.all, :id, :name, :prompt => 'Select Country' %>
    </div>

  <div id="field_state">

      <%= f.collection_select :state_id, State.all, :id, :name, {:prompt => 'Select State'}, { :multiple => true } %>
    </div>
    <%= link_to_remove_fields "remove", f %></div>
```

Comment: Can you post your views.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using has_many :user_states and class UserState instead?

Comment: @DickieBoy: I have added the views file in the update.

Comment: can you please list user_country_fields partial?

Comment: Please see to update1...

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested_form (https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form) to achieve this in following way,

```
 <%= nested_form_for(@user) do |f| %>
           ....

  <%= f.fields_for :user_countries do |country| %>
     <%= render "user_country_fields", :f => country %>
  <% end %>
  <div class="add_variant"><%= f.link_to_add "Add" :user_countries %></div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
```

Similarly, in partial

```
 <%= f.link_to_remove "Remove" %>
```

Comment: Actually this form_for(@user) itself is working. i.e., when i click on the add more it gets the value from partials and it displays it within this form but the id of the select box is generated different for each  like <select id="user_user_countries_attributes_1373608861127_country_id" name="user[user_countries_attributes][1373608861127][country_id]">. so how can i specify it in jquery to perform action for this id. This is where i am stuck with.

Comment: It is tricky to do, that's why nested_form_gem is created. You also provide you additional call-backs. But till you want to do it your self then look at this code screencast http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1?view=asciicast