# A dynamic dropdown (selectbox) menu in Rails with jQuery is not reversible

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms, drop-down-menu

On a website form controlled by Rails 6.1, I want to implement a "dynamic" or cascade dropdown menu so that the choices in the second dropdown varies depending on the selected item in the first dropdown menu.

Specifically, I have a `Person` model associated with `Country` and `Town` models. The relation is that a `Person` `belongs_to` a `Town`, which `belongs_to` a `Country` in `has_many`. Methods `Country#name` and `Town#name` are defined. In the *new* form on a website to `create` a `Person`, users select a *country* from a dropdown menu (select box) first and then a *town* in the second dropdown menu.

I basically followed the procedure [#88 Dynamic Select Menus (revised)](http://railscasts.com/episodes/88-dynamic-select-menus-revised), but rewrote it in the standard jQuery as opposed to Coffee in the Railcasts.

In short, I created a selectbox for the *towns* by using Rail's *form.[grouped_collection_select](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html#method-i-grouped_collection_select)* helper method; the part in the generated HTML contains many `OPTGROUP`, each of which correspods to a *country* where multiple child *towns* `belongs_to`. An associated jQuery script filters the second (i.e., *Town*) dropdown menu, comparing the selected item in the *Country* dropdown menu and the `LABEL` of each `OPTGROUP` for the *Town* dropdown menu (select box).

It kind of worked, but there is a serious flaw. Basically, it works at the first click. However, as soon as a user changes their mind and re-selects a different *country*, all the options for *towns* disappear. In other words, a user's first choice is irreversible. That is a poor interface.

How can it be fixed so users' choices are always reversible?

Below is the related parts in the form view (hrb.erb) and Javascript jQuery code. Here, `person` is a new instance of the model `Person`. It is tested with Rails 6.1.4, Ruby 3.0.1, and jQuery 3.5.1.

**erb.html for the form**:

```html
<%= form_with(model: person, local: true) do |form| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label 'town_id.country_id', 'Country'%>
    <%= form.collection_select town_id.country_id', Country.all,
        :id, :name, include_blank: true %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label 'place.town_id' %>
    <%= form.grouped_collection_select 'place.town_id', Country.all,
        :towns, :name, :id, :name, include_blank: true %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**Javascript jQuery**:

```js
 var contsel = "#"+$.escapeSelector('person_place.town_id.country_id');
 $(contsel).change(function(){
   var prefsel = "#"+$.escapeSelector('person_place.town_id');
   var contsel = "#"+$.escapeSelector('person_place.town_id.country_id');
   var country = $.escapeSelector($(contsel+' :selected').text());
   var towns = $(prefsel).html();
   var options = $(towns).filter("optgroup[label='"+country+"']").html();
   if (options) {
     $(prefsel).html(options);
   } else {
     $(prefsel).empty();
   }
 })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve dynamic dropdown menus with web application frameworks. As for the ways with Rails,
the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17215065/3577922) seems particularly well summarized.

I think the OP's way to use jQuery based on the `OPTGROUP` label has advantages that, if by any means not without drawbacks,

1. Rails-side coding is minimum,
2. a user can work out (and submit) a meaningful choice even if they disable the Javascript (OK, who would?).

The OP's Javascript code makes the generated HTML irreversible because it uses the `filter()` method to destructively modify the HTML. At the first action of `change()` prompted by a user's selection, the HTML is irreversibly modified. For example, once Country=Australia has been selected, the contents for all the *towns* except for those in Australia are removed, as far as the Javascript code is concerned. Hence, since any subsequent actions will be based on the modified HTML, the Javascript code knows nothing about the towns in any other *countries*.

The following Javascript jQuery code should fix the problem, making users' choices reversible.  It is based on the OP's sample code, and the first half is the same except for two additional lines.

```js
$(function(){
 var contsel = "#" + $.escapeSelector('person_place.town_id.country_id');
 var townsel = "#" + $.escapeSelector('person_place.town_id');
 $(townsel).parent().hide();
 $(contsel).change(function() {
   var townsel = "#" + $.escapeSelector('person_place.town_id');
   var contsel = "#" + $.escapeSelector('person_place.town_id.country_id');
   var country = $.escapeSelector($(contsel + ' :selected').text());
   var towns = $(townsel).html();
   var options = $(towns).filter("optgroup[label='" + country + "']").html();
   if (options) {
     $(townsel).parent().show();
     $(townsel).show();
     $(townsel + " optgroup").hide();
     $(townsel + " optgroup[label='" + country + "']").show();
     $(townsel).find('option:selected').prop("selected", false);
   } else {
     $(townsel).hide();
     $(townsel).parent().hide();
   }
 })
})
```

Here are a few points to note:

1. A primary difference is that this will `hide` and `show`, depending on a user's selection, and never remove or modify any other parts in the HTML.
2. To make the actions reversible, this explicitly `show` parts, which may have been hidden.
3. The entire selectbox for *towns* is hidden when the selected *country* contains no *towns* or no *country* has been selected.
4. When `change()` happens, i.e., when the user selects a new *country*, the user's previous selection, if it exists, is cleared. Without this, a user could technically submit the form data with a mutually contradictory combination like Country=Australia and Town=Nairobi.

Here's the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/masa_alpin/z1sjekvt/35/) of the sample code for experimenting. The full code is also available [at Github Gist](https://gist.github.com/masasakano/80d42a4f146f6888f072e04c6c8ad3abi).